# Toggle same div content with another div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to click on `div.square-1` and have it toggle with `div.square-2`

The div itself needs to act like a button, I don't want an external button to activate the toggle like they did on [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) documentation

Here is a sample of my code.

```
<a href="#" >
    <div class="square-box square-1">
        <h1>Square 1</h1>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <div class="square-box square-2">
        <h1>Square 2</h1>
    </div>
</a>


.square-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#square-1 {
    background-color: blue;
}

#square-2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on `div.square-1` it will get content of `div.square-2`

```js
var content1 = $('.square-1').html();
var content2 = $('.square-2').html();
var content = 1;

$('.square-1').click(function() {
  if (content == 1) {
    $(this).html(content2);
    content = 2;
  } else {
    $(this).html(content1);
    content = 1;
  }
});
```

```css
.square-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#square-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#square-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  <div class="square-box square-1">
    <h1>Square 1</h1>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="square-box square-2">
    <h1>Square 2</h1>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: It's almost there. Sorry, I should have mentioned I want the div to be a toggle. That is, clicking on div .square-1 gives me .square-2 and vice versa.

Comment: You want when you click again on `square-1` to get original content of `square-1` ?

Comment: Yeah, like I would click on square-1, I'll get square-2, and if i click back on square-2, it will revert back to square-2. .square-2 by default is hidden.

Comment: You mean it will revert back to `square-1`?

Comment: Yes. It just a toggle between square-1 and square2. Your solution seems to be the closest to what I am trying to achieve. It just needs to be able to toggle back and forth in between square-1 and square-2

Answer (score 0):

HI now try to this way

**[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**

**first of you save your** `square-1` `div` `content` than replace your `content` your `square-2` `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      
  $('.square-1').on('click', function(){
        
    
    var thisText =   $(this).find('h1').text();
    
    
    $('.square-2 h1').html(thisText);
      
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
.square-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.square-1 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.square-2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" >
    <div class="square-box square-1">
        <h1>Square 1</h1>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <div class="square-box square-2">
        <h1>Square 2</h1>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/), it may be the best suited method.